# cakePHP validation data before save

Tags: php, cakephp-2.1

I have a problem in my site created with cakePhp 2.x, when I try to register an account my form check all my rules of my fields and beforeSave crypt the password, but crypt the password before check the password(MatchPassword) with the confirm password and then return me the error tha the two password is't equal because the password is crypt with 40characters.

Here is my Model code, How can I solv this problem?

```
<?php
    //questo modello interessa lòa tabella User
    class User extends AppModel{
        public $name = 'User'; //non utilizzata nel sito è il nome del modello alla fine per migliorare la compatibilità

        public $validate = array(

            'password' => array(
                'non_vuoto' => array(
                    'rule'=> 'notEmpty',//non è vuoto metodo che eredito da appmodel
                    'message'=> 'La password non può essere vuota'  
                ),
                'min_lunghezza' => array(
                    'rule' => array('minLength',5),
                    'message' => 'La password deve contenere almeno 5 caratteri'
                ),
                'max_lunghezza' => array(
                    'rule' => array('maxLength',15),
                    'message' => 'La password deve contenere al massimo 15 caratteri'
                ),
                'password_uguale' => array(
                    'rule' => 'matchPasswords',
                    'message' => 'Not equal password'
                )
            ),
            'password_confirm' => array(
                'non_vuoto' => array(
                    'rule'=> 'notEmpty',//non è vuoto metodo che eredito da appmodel
                    'message'=> 'La password non può essere vuota'  
                )           
            )
        );


        public function matchPasswords($data){

            if ($data['password']==$this->data['User']['password_confirm']){
                return true;
            }

            $this->invalidate('password_confirm','Le due password non coincidono');
            return false;
        }


        public function beforeSave(){
            //crypt
            if (isset($this->data['User']['password'])){
                $this->data['User']['password']=AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: in your matchPasswords function: shouldn't it be like this `$this->data['User']['password']==$this->data['User']['password_confirm']` ?

Comment: No because with "$data['password']" I take the password not crypted in theory. I try with $this->data['User']['password']==$this->data['User']['password_confirm'] but doesn't work same

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem -- I'm not sure if it's *exactly* what you were asking -- but I needed to validate my model, before the beforeSave() rules were applied.

I found CakePHP's [Validating Data from the Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html) page helpful. Basically, you set the data

```
$this->ModelName->set($this->request->data);
```

Then you can check the model's validates() method...

```
if ($this->ModelName->validates()) { // ...
```

Then, you can decide whether to save the model or show the user an error using, e.g., $this->Session->setFlash().